# Sliding panel in a table

Tags: asp.net

I want to display in my web page couple of show times and the list of movies under it.

The display would be like this -

Show Time 6.30 PM

```
   Movie 1
   Movie 2
   Movie 3
```

Show Time 9.30 PM

```
   Movie 1
   Movie 2
   Movie 3
```

I want to display it in such a way that when I Click on "Show Time 6.30 PM" it would display the movies under that show and wont display anything under "Show Time 9.30 PM". Now when I click on "Show Time 9.30 PM", all the contents inside "Show Time 6.30 PM" should shrink and the list of movies should be available
in "Show Time 9.30 PM".

I need some idea on how to do this, will it be achieved using a sliding panel, or is there any other control.
Note - For the show times and movie details I have a collection which I am binding it to a repaeter control.

What I am looking is for a SINGLE sliding panel which floats around every row in the table, So if Row 1 is clicked the panel displays the show times under it, when Row 2 is clicked, the data inside row 1 Is shrinked and the panel floats to down displaying the movies under Row 2.

Please shed some info on this. Thanks.

Regards

Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done similar effects with the Accordion control from the Ajax Control Toolkit.

Take a look and see if that will fit the bill.

http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/Accordion/Accordion.aspx

An alternative with more of a menu-like effect is the popup control.

http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx

Comment: Links are not available.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)?  It's fast and easy to implement, and will do everything you need.